# Delay on loading in elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a list of `li` elements that I'm trying to get to load in one by one.

So you hit the page, first one moves in using css `transform: translateX()` from the left and fades in. Then the next, and so forth.

My `index.html` looks like :

```
<div class="list_wrapper">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
</div>
```

I have a few styles that add a background image and display block etc. to get the `li` tags to line up side-by-side but I've not added them in because I don't want to make the question too long.

EDIT :

Each one of my `li` tags has the styles to start them further left so the load in moves them like so : `transform: translateX(-10%);`

My jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $('.list_wrapper li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 500).css({
      'opacity': '1',
      'transform': 'translateX(0%)'
    })
  })
});
```

Whenever I hit the page it adds the styles to the `li` tags straight away. It doesn't do the jQuery `delay` that I'm trying to pass through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why you dont use `setTimeout` so simple and try this

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('li').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('li').eq(i).css({
       'transform': 'translateX(0%)',
        'opacity': 1
      });
    }, 1000*i)
  })
})
```

```css
li{
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-10%);
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list_wrapper">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
</div>
<button>ok</button>
```

Comment: OP.. Accept it as soon as you can! ;)

Comment: Cheers man! This worked. I'll accept as answer as soon as I can :) codeHeart below answer helped me also. I misunderstood how to use jQuery `delay` method

Answer (score 2):

As the manual mentions here https://api.jquery.com/delay/

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

So you cannot use `.delay()` the way that you intend to, a `setTimeout` might help in the effect that you are trying to achieve, by sending of the next li to be show to the function in `setTimeOut`

More from the manual

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Comment: Cheers man! This helped clear up why the `delay()` wasn't doing what I thought it should have been doing

Answer (score 0):

You may use setTimeout() instead:

```
$('.list_wrapper li').each(function(i) {
    var $item = $(this);
      setTimeout(function () {
        $item.css({
          'opacity': '1',
          'transform': 'translateX(0%)'
        });
      }, (i + 1) * 500);
});
```